# Export all data referenced by a foreign key to data grid

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, entity-framework

I created a small application for User manipulation (Add , Update and Delete ) and for their activities. I have a database with 2 tables: First users and the second one Activities. The relationship is one to many with a foreign key at the second table which is the `User_ID` from the first table. In my front end I have a form with a data grid with all all the members in the user table. When double clicking at one of them a second frame opens with all the activities of that User.
In order to retrieve the activities of that person I do the following:

```
void updateActions()
        {
            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                dgActions.DataSource = db.Actions.Where(x => x.Client_ID.Equals(Main.client.Client_ID)).ToList<Action>();

        }
```

This works ok but it doesn't look very efficient because every time I have to iterate to all the table. I see that entity framework in the generated code generates an `ICollection<Activities>`. Is there any way to make use of it and make my application more efficient.

I mean to do something like this.

```
void updateActions()
        {
            using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                //dgActions.DataSource = db.Actions.Where(x => x.Client_ID.Equals(Main.client.Client_ID)).ToList<Action>();
                dgActions.DataSource = Main.client.Actions.ToList<Action>();
        }
```

This get's the following error

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: 'The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.'
```

Here is the hole code.

```
 namespace I2S
    {
        public partial class Main : Form
        {
           public static Client client = new  Client();


            public Main()
            {
                InitializeComponent();

            }


            private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Clear();
            }
            void Clear()
            {
                txtName.Text = txtPhone.Text = txtAddress.Text = "";
                btnAdd.Text = "Add";
                btnDelete.Enabled = false;
                client.Client_ID = 0;
            }

            private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if(MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this user ?" , "Delete User" , MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                    {
                        var entry = db.Entry(client);
                        if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
                            db.Clients.Attach(client);
                        db.Clients.Remove(client);

                        db.SaveChanges();
                        MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");

                    }
                    Clear();
                    update_Grid();


                }
            }

            private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                client.Name = txtName.Text.Trim();
                client.Address = txtAddress.Text.Trim();
                client.Telephone = txtPhone.Text.Trim();

                using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                {
                    if (client.Client_ID == 0)
                    {
                        db.Clients.Add(client);
                        db.SaveChanges();


                        MessageBox.Show("New user added");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Entry(client).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                        db.SaveChanges();



                        MessageBox.Show("User Updated Successfully");
                    }
                    Clear();
                    update_Grid();

                }


            }

            private void Main_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                update_Grid();

            }


            void update_Grid()
            {
                dgClients.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                {
                    dgClients.DataSource = db.Clients.ToList<Client>();


                }
            }
            private void dgClients_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {

                if (dgClients.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
                {
                    client.Client_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgClients.CurrentRow.Cells["Client_ID"].Value);
                }
                using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                {
                    client = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Client_ID == client.Client_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                    txtName.Text = client.Name;
                    txtAddress.Text = client.Address;
                    txtPhone.Text = client.Telephone;

                }
                btnAdd.Text = "Update";
                btnDelete.Enabled = true;

            }
            private void dgClients_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if (dgClients.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
                {
                    client.Client_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dgClients.CurrentRow.Cells["Client_ID"].Value);
                }
                Form2 actionsForm = new Form2();



                actionsForm.Show();
            }




        }
    }


    namespace I2S
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            Action action = new Action();

            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Clear();
                txtDateStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                txtTimeStart.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;
                txtDateEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                txtTimeEnd.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Time;


                btDeleteAction.Enabled = false;
                updateActions();
            }

            private void dgActions_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
            {
                if(dgActions.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
                {
                    action.Action_Id = Convert.ToInt32(dgActions.CurrentRow.Cells["Action_ID"].Value);
                }
                using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                {
                    action = db.Actions.Where(x => x.Action_Id == action.Action_Id).FirstOrDefault();
                    txtActionDescription.Text = action.Action_Desc;
                    txtDateStart.Text = action.Action_Beggin.Date.ToString();
                    txtTimeStart.Text = action.Action_Beggin.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                    txtDateEnd.Text = action.Action_End.Date.ToString();
                    txtTimeEnd.Text = action.Action_End.TimeOfDay.ToString();
                }
                btAddAction.Text = "Update";
                btDeleteAction.Enabled = true;

            }

            private void btDeleteAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to delete this action ?", "Delete Action", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
                {
                    using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                    {
                        var entry = db.Entry(action);
                        if (entry.State == System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached)
                            db.Actions.Attach(action);
                        db.Actions.Remove(action);
                        MessageBox.Show("Action Sucesfully Removed");

                        db.SaveChanges();

                    }
                    Clear();
                    updateActions();
                }
            }

            private void btAddAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                action.Action_Desc = txtActionDescription.Text.Trim();

                action.Action_Beggin = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateStart.Value.Date + txtTimeStart.Value.TimeOfDay);
                action.Action_End = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateEnd.Value.Date + txtTimeEnd.Value.TimeOfDay);
                action.Client_ID = Main.client.Client_ID;

                using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                {
                    if (action.Action_Id == 0)
                    {
                        db.Actions.Add(action);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        MessageBox.Show("New action added");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        db.Entry(action).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;


                        db.SaveChanges();

                        MessageBox.Show("Action Succesfully Updated");
                    }
                }
                Clear();
                updateActions();

            }
            void updateActions()
            {
                using (I2SEntities1 db = new I2SEntities1())
                    dgActions.DataSource = db.Actions.Where(x => x.Client_ID.Equals(Main.client.Client_ID)).ToList<Action>();
            }



            private void btClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Clear();
            }
            void Clear()
            {
                txtActionDescription.Text = txtDateStart.Text =  txtTimeStart.Text = txtDateEnd.Text = txtTimeEnd.Text= "";
                btDeleteAction.Enabled = false;
                btAddAction.Text = "Add";
                action.Action_Id = 0;
            }
        }
    }

 The DTO's for `Client` and `Actions` :

        namespace I2S
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class Client
        {
            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
            public Client()
            {
                this.Actions = new HashSet<Action>();
            }

            public int Client_ID { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public string Telephone { get; set; }

            [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
            public virtual ICollection<Action> Actions { get; set; }
        }
    }


    namespace I2S
    {
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;

        public partial class Action
        {
            public int Action_Id { get; set; }
            public string Action_Desc { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime Action_Beggin { get; set; }
            public System.DateTime Action_End { get; set; }
            public int Client_ID { get; set; }

            public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
        }
    }

    namespace I2S
    {
        using System;
        using System.Data.Entity;
        using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

        public partial class I2SEntities1 : DbContext
        {
            public I2SEntities1()
                : base("name=I2SEntities1")
            {
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
            }

            public virtual DbSet<Action> Actions { get; set; }
            public virtual DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If two users with the application from different computers use it at the same time, querying the database would avoid weird behavior (like one of them uptating the data the other one deleted)

Comment: @bradbury9 so you suggest that I keep it as it is with the query in the database?

Comment: If users can work with the same data at the same time, accesing the database is fine, you would avoid weird conflicts.

Comment: How many rows are we talking about? You might want to consider using IEnumerbale<Actions> instead and implement paging

Comment: @Austin T French Too many rows. But why not to use the ICollection<Actions>. I actually avoid weird conflicts because if I delete update or add in the database i connect to it. I will upload the hole code to make it more clear.